# MissingRequiredArgument: context is a required argument that is missing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, message

Im Still New (Because I Took A Break And Forgot Almost Everything). I Was Coding An AFK Bot And This Happened...

Error: `MissingRequiredArgument: context is a required argument that is missing.`

Code:

```
@client.command()
async def start(ctx,context,user: discord.Member):
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel
    name = context.author.display_name
    author = context.author
    guild = context.guild
    AFKrole = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="AFK")
    if not AFKrole:
        AFKrole = await guild.create_role(name="AFK")
    await context.author.edit(nick=f"[AFK]{name}")
    await author.add_roles(AFKrole)
    await ctx.send(f"AFK Mode Started For **{author}**.")
    gt = await client.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=180)
    if gt.content.lower() == "afk stop":
        await context.author.edit(nick=f"{name}")
        await author.remove_roles(AFKrole)
        await ctx.send(f"AFK Mode Stopped For **{author}**.")
    else:
        pass
```

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove context parameter and replace any `context` part in the code with just ctx. ctx is already context.

Ex.

```py
name = ctx.author.display_name
author = ctx.author
guild = ctx.guild
```